# arduino serial HELP ME

Tags: arduino, serial-port, arduino-uno, serial-communication

I am trying to get an LED to light up when a certain message comes through on the serial port but nothing is working! **please help me!!**

```
int awsState = "AWS:0";   // for incoming serial data

 void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);   
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

    // send data only when you receive data:
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
            // read the incoming byte:
            awsState = Serial.read();

            // say what you got:
            Serial.print(incomingByte);
            Serial.println("Good");
            if (awsState == "AWS:1"){

              digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
            }
    else if (awsState == "AWS:0"){
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is defined `incomingByte` ? Look at ["Arduino - SoftwareSerial: read"](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerialRead)... That function returns only one character at a time, not the complete message.

Comment: Please always do a **Tools > Auto Format** on your code before posting it.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way to read a command from the `Serial` link.

**Step 1** - declare a String to store input data as global variable

```
String awsState;
```

Instead of:

```
int awsState = "AWS:0";
```

**Step 2** - initialize the String in the `setup()`

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);   
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
    awsState= "";
}
```

**Step 3** - extract all received character, display them and process the command

```
void loop() {
    while (Serial.available() > 0) {
        // read all received characters
        char rec =  Serial.read();
        // until <return> character
        if (rec != '\n') {
            awsState += rec; 
        }
        else {
            Serial.print(awsState);
            Serial.println("Good");
            if (awsState == "AWS:1"){
              digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
            }
            else if (awsState == "AWS:0"){
              digitalWrite(13, LOW);
            }
            // reset the command to wait the next one
            awsState= "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason for downvote ? The proposed answer explains where errors were located and a easy to understand solution.

Comment: @DanielHolmes, did you try it ? I have tried to simulate, because I haven't my Arduino with me.